# Can an intrinsic semiconductor not be used as a base?

Tags: bjt, semiconductors

I'm studying transistors. After having learned how a transistor works, I can't help thinking that we could have an intrinsic semiconductor as a base.

This is because it would reduce recombinations. Could anyone please explain me how would it make the transistor different?
Just consider my transistor which is an intrinsic semiconductor between two N-type regions.

Then forward-biasing the emitter-base junction would result in electrons moving into the base (intrinsic) because of diffusion, and then reverse-biasing between base and collector would push the electrons to the collector.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Maybe physics.se is better for this question.

Comment: :(       I previously put it in physics. I was told it would be best answered if it were here

Comment: physics.se is totally useless for condensed matter questions. EE is a better fit @Andyaka

Comment: Is this a theoretical question? because I doubt it is possible to get the correct emitter and collector doping without *also* doping the base region... (look at the schematic crosssection of a BJT)